# Python- Getting a specific information from an array

Tags: python-2.7

If I have this array how could I get the values of the distances?

```
    [ 0, { 'labels': [ 0, 0,1]  'distances' : [10.132, 10.341, 13.314 ]}]
```

I mean how could I print the value 10.132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscript into the array, then subscript again into the dictionary (I had to add a comma to avoid the syntax error in your dictionary, by the way):

```
myarray = [ 0, { 'labels': [ 0, 0,1],  'distances' : [10.132, 10.341, 13.314 ]}]

myarray[1]['distances']
Out[3]: [10.132, 10.341, 13.314]
```

If you want each distance, subscript again:

```
myarray[1]['distances'][0]
Out[4]: 10.132
```

If this is still isn't making sense, add a comment, and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: @aladdinhammodi If it helped, could you please accept it? I'm gunning for points here :)